# Loading data and symbol them to the map dynamically

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-android

I am using ArcGIS SDK for Android 10.2.2, and we want to add some geographic data(graphic) to the map.

While our data is deployed by a common web service(no geographic web service like wms or wfs) which can be queried by a bbox.

Now we want to add the queried point to the map after the map zoom,pan or something else which make the map update.

But it seems that the only map event we can use is `OnZoomListener` and `OnPanListener`, but we found that we the view(no matter center or the resolution) of the map is changed by program like this:

```
mapView.setResolution(...); // or
mapView.centerAt(...);
```

These listeners will not be triggered.

So I tried to make the points a kind of `Layer`, because I think the layer must be sensitive to the map update event, but I have see almost all the api about the layer, I can not found a class to extend.

In fact, the `ArcgisFeatureLayer` is the most close to our requirement, it seems that it can automatically load new data according to the map view, but we do not deploy our data by arcgis feature service and we do not plan to.

So I wonder if there is an alternative way to make it work?

---

Update the data model:

for example, we get data from this url:

```
http://server/ws?bbox=30,30,40,40&xx=xx
```

Then we will get:

```
[{id:1,x:33,y:44,name:'xx'},{id:2.....}]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data you are trying to add to the map? You mention a service, do you have a url to inspect? Is the data features, e.g. points? Or tile base service?

Comment: @jdONeill: See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the ArcGIS Android API does not allow for extending feature layers.  Your workflow should be to convert your return data into `Point`s using the return x & y values. You can then use your `Point` to create a `Graphic`, with any attribute data you want to include and a `Symbol` representation, then add your `Graphic`s to a `GraphicsLayer`.